# Implement an algorithm to delete a node in the middle of a single linked list, given only access to that node

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Example input: the node ‘c’ from the linked list a->b->c->d->e Result: nothing is returned, but the new linked list looks like a->b->d->e

I do understand that ppl have already asked this question before, but since my reputation is not high enough yet, I couldn't ask my question in that thread. so here goes my quesetion:
So in the solution, when deleting the middle node we do:

```
public static boolean deleteNode(LinkedListNode n) {
    if (n == null || n.next == null) {
         return false; // Failure
    }
    LinkedListNode next = n.next;
    n.data = next.data;
    n.next = next.next;
    return true;
}
```

But what I don't understand is that why can't I just do n = next?
It is probably a trivial question, but I didn't seem to find a good explanation for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the code you wrote would look like this:

```
bool deleteNode(LinkedListNode* n) {
    if (n == null || (*n).next == null) {
         return false; // Failure
    }
    LinkedListNode* next = (*n).next;
    (*n).data = (*next).data;
    (*n).next = (*next).next;
    return true;
}
```

So what does that mean? When you call this method, in C++ it would look like this:

```
LinkedListNode* listNode = new LinkedListNode();
deleteNode(&listNode);
```

This is important, because that means you're just sending an address over, and not the entire object. This means that you don't actually have access to the node you gave as a parameter to the method, you only have a reference to its address.

Basically, in Java, you can't do the following C++ code:

```
*n = *next;
```

You can't modify the listNode object that's outside of the method. You only get its address. And you are only modifying the copy of its address, not the address itself.

Basically, it's because in Java, the pointer of the class is passed by value (as a copy), and primitives are also passed by value (as a copy).

Comment: Its 'bool' in c++, not 'boolean' data type, as stated in this example. A small correction.

Answer (score 2):

If you just do `n = next` then you have only changed what object your local reference variable `n` refers to; you haven't modified any part of the list.

The trick to "deleting" the current node is to overwrite it with the next one:

```
n.data = next.data;
n.next = next.next;
```

Now you are modifying fields of the object that is referred to by `n`, which is a part of the actual list.

Answer (score 0):

somehow, it overwrites the current node which is supposed to be deleted with the 
data of next node to it,and delete the next node.

```
LinkedListNode next = n.next;
n.data = next.data;
n.next = next.next;
```

That is how the code comes.